# How to detect if a web page is running from a website or local file system

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to javascript. How can I detect if my javascript is being run from a web site (http://) vs a local file.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
switch(window.location.protocol) {
   case 'http:':
   case 'https:':
     //remote file over http or https
     break;
   case 'file:':
     //local file
     break;
   default: 
     //some other protocol
}
```

Comment: This is not true. A site can be hosted locally and still use the 'http' protocol when hosted on a web server locally.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and an answer below addresses this below, but I think the original poster was asking specifically about http: vs. file: protocol based on how his question is phrased.

Answer (score 3):

For testing different 'kinds' of local, all at once:

```
// Returns the page location type
// 0 (falsey) = Local file, direct from disk (file://path/to/file.html)
// 1 (truthy) = Virtually remote file, from local server (http://localhost)
// 2 (truthy) = Remote file from remote server (http://example.com)

function locationType(){
    if( window.location.protocol == 'file:' ){ return 0; }
    if( !window.location.host.replace( /localhost|127\.0\.0\.1/i, '' ) ){ return 2; }
    return 1;
}
```

Rationale: you may want to test for whether the page is a) on a remote server, or b) on a local server (same computer, for testing, like with AMP), or c) a local file, retrieved directly from disk via the "file://" protocol.

Note that this doesn't handle every possible edge case. For example, you can technically redirect different IPs to "localhost", and other non-"file://" schemes (like "foo://") may in fact represent local access. But it works for most cases and can be otherwise tweaked as needed

Testing only for "http" and "https" is a bit limited, since there are dozens of other LAN and WAN network schemes in use around the world. Whether or not they're local or can even use HTML/JS code may vary, of course ([IANA URI Schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)).

Comment: Not the exact way I'd do this, but upvote for checking for localhost.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah admittedly a bit awkward, though for my own use I wanted a single function where I could test for just true/false if I wanted to make sure it was a "true" local file, but also test the integer value if I wanted to know if it was on localhost/remote. You could split this into three different functions, and break apart the regex into `( window.location.host == 'localhost' || window.location.host == '127.0.0.1' || window.location.host == '' )` if it's too complex.

Comment: Please note that a HTML file run on localhost doesn't need to have the "localhost" part of URL or IP "127.0.0.1". Some users can modify their "hosts" file inside their "Windows" directory and assign different URL and different IP – for example, for one of my projects, I use "127.0.0.4 projectname.local".

Answer (score 3):

I used a slightly modifed version compared to @Beejor that also handles a possible port. It allows setting a base `uriHost` for e. g. ajax/jquery requests that may need the host portion if running as local file instead of running via SSH tunnel or directly via IP:Port. The detection portion is in the if-else conditions.

```js
var uriHost = "";
if (window.location.protocol === "file:") {
  console.log("Running as local file!");
  // like: file://<path>/index.html
  uriHost = "http://<my-host-or-ip>:<my-port>";
} else if (
  !window.location.host.replace(/(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:\d+)?/i, "")
) {
  console.log("Running on local server (ssh tunnel etc.)");
  // like: "http://127.0.0.1:<my-port>"
} else {
  console.log("Running normally, via web server");
  // like: "http://<my-host-or-ip>:<my-port>"
}
// now do something with uriHost, e.g. for ajax uris etc.
```

To check if running as local file (i.e. `file://`) only checking `window.location.protocol === "file:"` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Other ways to do this:

```
if (/^h/.test(document.location)) {
  // remote file over http or https
} else {
  // local file
}
```

or

```
if (document.location.host) {
  // remote file over http or https
} else {
  // local file
}
```

or ([slow](http://jsperf.com/test-protocol-regex-vs-indexof), not recommended)

```
if ((''+document.location).indexOf('http') === 0) {
// if (document.location.protocol.indexOf('http') === 0) { // another way
  // remote file over http or https
} else {
  // local file
}
```